# JQuery click function not working even after $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm trying some JQuery basics at [this site](https://biglietti.italotreno.it/Booking_Acquisto_Ricerca.aspx), but when I am trying to click a station using the jQuery click function, it does nothing.

I've researched a bit and some say that adding `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` fixes it but doesn't. I hope you can help me guys. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#departure-city_').click();
    var milano = $('div.stations-body').find("span[data-code='MC_']");
    milano.click(function() {
        alert('hello');
    }); 
});
```

$('#departure-city_').click(); works but not the click function for the variable milano.

To give you a better picture on what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to create a script that automatically browses that site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fire the click event after attaching the handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var milano = $('div.stations-body').find("span[data-code='MC_']");
    milano.click(function() {
       alert('hello');
    }); 
    $('#departure-city_').click();       
});
```

Comment: I may not have been clear in my question. $('#departure-city_').click(); works but not the click function for the variable milano. Can you help me further? Thanks

Comment: The click function works on the dropdown button, but when the container shows up, clicking any of its content does not work.

Comment: @RudolfGuiamoy :  bind event handler ..... `$('body').on('click','div.stations-body span[data-code='MC_']",function() {
       alert('hello');
    });`

Comment: Using 
`$('#departure-city_').click();
$('body').on('click',"div.stations-body span[data-code='MC_']",function() { alert('hello'); });` does not still work. Can you suggest any other way of clicking the dropdown box then selecting any item in the container? Thank you